# What is the right way to store user's quiz/test answer?

Tags: javascript, json, database, algorithm

I build quiz/test application.
It has 2 tables in database.

First one, **Quiz table**:

```
quizes
--------
title
.....
questions
```

**Questions structure**

```
{
"answer": "rightanswer", 
"index": 0, 
"question": "What is the right answer?", 
"answers": [
     "answers1", 
     "answers2", 
     "answers3", 
     "answers4"
   ], 
}
```

And I have separate table to store users answers (**user_answers**).

```
user_answers
-----
id
quiz_id
.....
answers
```

So, my question is, what is the right way to store user answers.

**First way:**

Once user open quiz page copy all *questions* to *user_answers*/**answer** column. And just push into question his answer and mark, and then update *user_answers*/**answer**.

**Second way**

Once user open quiz page init blueprint json:

```
{
  "index": 0
  "mark": 5
}
```

After answer on push this json to array and update *user_answers*/**answer**, and every time just merge questions and answers arrays like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < userAnswers.length; j++) {
        if (userAnswers[j].index == i) {
            questions[i].mark = userAnswers[j].mark;
         }
     } 
 }
```

Both of ways have disadvantages
In first one you have to make copy of questions a lot of times.
In second one loop will take a lot of time if quiz has many questions.

So what is the right way?

Comment: Time to give each  each question and each answer unique ID's. Then give each answer a question_id and you then have relationships to match them regardless how they are stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest a better a way to store your questions, 
Lets say you have a question schema:

```
{ 
  "qid" : 0,
  "question": "What is the answer",
  "answers": [
    { "text" : "Answer one" , "isAnswer" : false },
    { "text" : "Answer two" , "isAnswer" : false },
    { "text" : "Answer three" , "isAnswer" : true }
  ]
}
```

And for answers schema

```
{
  "quizId" : 10,
  "qid" : 0,
  "answerId" : 0 // <- here index , but you can take unique answer ids also for a question
}
```

this way you just need run one loop to get the answers , or write a little complex aggregate query to get the answers

Comment: Plus you can incorporate questions , where there are multiple answers possible in this schema

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you, 
besides I prefer the later, your second solution is a loop and it's happening on the client's machine, so it's not too important! 
I think it's fast enough to generate 1000 question less than a second so it's ok!

Answer (score 0):

i'd probably just have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INTEGER,
  `quiz_id` INTEGER,
  `quiz_question_id` INTEGER, 
  `answer` VARCHAR(200),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX no_duplicate_answers ON answers (user_id,quiz_id,quiz_question_id);
```

Comment: @NickD That's the silliest thing I ever heard. "Over 5,000 quizzes" means you out-grew a JSON file about 4,900 quizzes ago.

Comment: @NickD idk what db you use, but 5000 quizzes, even if they have 100 questions each, with 10,000 users having completed every single quiz, would be ~5 million records, which would be no problem for MySQL / SQLite / MariaDB / PostgreSQL